# When editing recurring contributions or changing payment details donor see "Network Error - Unable To Reach The Server"

Tags: civicontribute

Drupal 7.61 
CiviCRM 5.4.1

When you click Edit or Change Billing on recurring donations, donors get "Network Error - Unable to Reach the Server"
I do get a console Error and a Warning.

Warning = jquery.min.js?pjxwd7:4 [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check xhr.spec.whatwg.org.

Error = VM1127:1 GET secure.radiusinternational.org/civicrm/… 403

Comment: is everything else working fine? eg Editing standard Contributions etc

Comment: Yes, everything else seems to be fine.